# Merge tag [wtk] into [java-wireless-toolkit]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

Tags [wtk](/questions/tagged/wtk) and [java-wireless-toolkit](/questions/tagged/java-wireless-toolkit) should be merged as these refer to the same SDK.

<sub>*java-wireless-toolkit* appeals to official name of the SDK, while *wtk* is an abbreviation popular among its users.</sub>